# "xxx.scss" is not in the SourceMap error in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I'm following Laravel documentation and have this file structure:

[image]

In `app.scss` I have:

```
@import 'style12';
.real-demo{

}
```

and in `style12.scss` some css code which i try to import.

When I run `npm run dev` I get following error:

```
Module build failed: Error: "../../resources/assets/sass/style12.scss" is not in the SourceMap.
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_sourceContentFor [as sourceContentFor] (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:704:13)
    at SourceMapGenerator.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:235:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SourceMapGenerator_applySourceMap [as applySourceMap] (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:234:32)
    at MapGenerator.applyPrevMaps (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\postcss\lib\map-generator.js:146:22)
    at MapGenerator.generateMap (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\postcss\lib\map-generator.js:194:46)
    at MapGenerator.generate (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\postcss\lib\map-generator.js:297:25)
    at LazyResult.stringify (C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:294:24)
    at C:\Users\mixei\Desktop\Projects\westcredit\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:231:27
```

Also here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing the name of `style21.scss` to `_style12.scss`?

Comment: what Laravel Mix version are you using? Any extra webpack configs ?